# Ng-model com Button

Tags: angularjs

Bom dia,
Eu faço um loop para pegar "name" em um array e cada "name", possui variaveis com informações. Preciso que o ng-model receba o valor do "name" quando eu clicar no "button" para ai sim eu poder fazer um loop dentro deste "name".

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="rep in list.report">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item " ng-model="ctrl.x=" style="width:450px;height:35px" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
       {{rep.name}}
  </button></div>
```

Comment: Tá meio confuso pra mim... Tu vai dar um repeat, vai gerar vários botões com cada rep e o name dele como descrição do botão. Ao clicar o botão tu quer pegar os valores que tem dentro do name? (name é um objeto/array também?)

Comment: É isso mesmo que você explicou.